SLD with double rules
I have a layer in which the symbology is done by a mix of two values, in this case "Place" and "Stand". Basically, "place" give the Offset of the point, meanwhile "stand" give the color (or better, the correct svg but one step at the time) of the point.
In QGIS I did a rule based on the stand, (Stand 1 -> Red, ...) meanwhile the offset was given by another rule in the point specification (if Reactor=1, -10,-10,...). This is definitely not supported in SLD. The only solution that I have find until now is to make for every point two rules, as seen in the code under.
However, this isn't very practical, because i have a total of 5 places with 6 different stand possible, and such a big matrix isn't easy to change in case an SVG need to be changed and also the symbology that appear after that is totally non readable.
Can you help me to find a better solution?
Changing directly the position of the point is not an option and I'm trying to import this layer on GeoServer.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" version="1.1.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>PlaceAndStand</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>Place1</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Place 1</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Place 1</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Place</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Stand</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d7191c</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>7</se:Size>
              <se:Displacement>
                <se:DisplacementX>-18</se:DisplacementX>
                <se:DisplacementY>-18</se:DisplacementY>
              </se:Displacement>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Place 1 S2</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Place 1 S2</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Place</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Stand</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#987db7</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>7</se:Size>
              <se:Displacement>
                <se:DisplacementX>-18</se:DisplacementX>
                <se:DisplacementY>-18</se:DisplacementY>
              </se:Displacement>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Place 2</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Place 2</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Place</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Stand</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#d7191c</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>7</se:Size>
              <se:Displacement>
                <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
                <se:DisplacementY>-18</se:DisplacementY>
              </se:Displacement>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Place 2</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>Place 2</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:And>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Place</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>Stand</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:And>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PointSymbolizer>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
                <se:Fill>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#987db7</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Fill>
                <se:Stroke>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
                  <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
                </se:Stroke>
              </se:Mark>
              <se:Size>7</se:Size>
              <se:Displacement>
                <se:DisplacementX>0</se:DisplacementX>
                <se:DisplacementY>-18</se:DisplacementY>
              </se:Displacement>
            </se:Graphic>
          </se:PointSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>


I think that you need to look at the recode function that should let you do something like:
      <se:PointSymbolizer>
        <se:Graphic>
          <se:Mark>
            <se:WellKnownName>circle</se:WellKnownName>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">
              <ogc:Function name="Recode">
                  <!-- Value to transform -->
                  <ogc:PropertyName>Place</ogc:PropertyName>

                  <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>#6495ED</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                  <ogc:Literal>#458973</ogc:Literal>
...
                </ogc:Function>
              </se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:Mark>
          <se:Size>7</se:Size>
          <se:Displacement>
            <se:DisplacementX>
               <ogc:Function name="Recode">
                  <ogc:PropertyName>Stand</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>-18</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Function>
            </se:DisplacementX>
            <se:DisplacementY>

               <ogc:Function name="Recode">
                  <ogc:PropertyName>Stand</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>-18</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
                      <ogc:Literal>18</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Function>
            </se:DisplacementY>
          </se:Displacement>
        </se:Graphic>
      </se:PointSymbolizer>


Thanks a lot, it worked perfectly! I didn't know about the "recode" function.
